# unexpected error while parsing input invalid uiautomator hierarchy file

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use **traceview** tool to check application performane,but facing some problem and cant figure out.

1. Initially i used this command to open traceview

   `E:\sdk\android-sdk\tools>monitor E:\calc` calc is my log file for traceview, traceview window opened but terminal replied something like this,
   **The standalone version of traceview is deprecated.
   Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor) instead.**
2. Then i closed window and tried to use monitor like this,
   `E:\sdk\android-sdk\tools>monitor E:\calc` now i am getting popup with error,
   **could not open selected vm debug port 8700**.
   As per stackoverflow solutions i tried to close already running DDMS instance by closing eclipse and then fired following command,
   `E:\sdk\android-sdk\tools>monitor E:\calc`.
   But now i am getting popup with error **unexpected error while parsing input invalid uiautomator hierarchy file**
3. Finally i tried same command 3 to 4 times with no luck and after that i got new error,
   **an error has occurred see the log file  E:\sdk\android-sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\configuration\1411708804511.log**

1411708804511.log file contains following info,

```
!SESSION 2014-09-26 10:50:04.337 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.736
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.740
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.741
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.771
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.772
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.773
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.775
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.779
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.781
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.782
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.783
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:04.808
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.733
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.734
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.snowball_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [26] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239 [90] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548 [93] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.756
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548 [94] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [137] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522 [138] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543 [146] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200 [149] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.v20120523-1540 [151] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524 [163] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [165] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.757
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-26 10:50:05.759
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.URIUtil.toURI(URIUtil.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

How to solve problem please help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was just having the same issue while attempting to run the standalone monitor (sans Eclipse), until I found this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72420

In a nutshell:

1. Ensure you have no other `monitor.exe` (if on Windows) or `monitor` (if OS X / Linux) process running. If you do, kill it.
2. Run `rm -rf $HOME/.android/monitor-workspace` or remove the directory manually

This did the trick for me: I was able to run DDMS without the Null Pointer Exception after following these steps.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I had no other process but I just deleted $HOME/.android/monitor-workspace.

Comment: Be sure to run the above command while the Android Device monitor is not running... can save you 30 sec there

Comment: Number 2. worked for me. I think opening my project in Eclipse messed with the settings, after deleting the folder it loaded up no problem. Thanks!

Comment: So essentially the error is caused by a screw-up in the monitor-workspace metadata.  When you remove it, you force it to be rebuilt to defaults.  Worked for me too.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you. The first step is so importance. I found  solutions in other webs but all of them didn't mention the first step so that I failed to solve. Thank you again.