# Android Device Monitor fails with "unexpected error while parsing input: Invalid uiautomator hierarchy file

Tags: java, android

I looked through others questions with this similar issue but the error log and stack trace are different.  In my case I am running on OSX 10.11.6.  With Android Device Monitor, Version: 25.2.2.

When I start Android Device Monitor (monitor) at the command line, an error dialog is displayed:

[image: Android Device Monitor error dialog]

In the stack dump, it's looking for the file

> /var/folders/5g/8_lp975j6h3d67sc32sqkq3c0000gp/T/uiautomatorviewer_6077102350746730072/dump_7454833342327499247.uix

I looked in that directory and it's right, the file doesn't exist.

The GUI does display, but it is unusable.  How can I fix this?

Here is the full stack dump.

> $ monitor
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/5g/8_lp975j6h3d67sc32sqkq3c0000gp/T/uiautomatorviewer_6077102350746730072/dump_7454833342327499247.uix (No such file or directory)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:622)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
>       at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:328)
>       at com.android.uiautomator.tree.UiHierarchyXmlLoader.parseXml(UiHierarchyXmlLoader.java:130)
>       at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorModel.(UiAutomatorModel.java:51)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.editors.UiAutomatorViewer.createPartControl(UiAutomatorViewer.java:105)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:313)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:861)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:841)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:113)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:321)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:242)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1115)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:520)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:505)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:74)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:894)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:98)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:644)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:641)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:702)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:681)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:987)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>   null rootnode after parsing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first kill `monitor.exe` if exists, and remove `$HOME/.android/monitor-workspace`.

Corresponding issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72420

See also this question: [unexpected error while parsing input invalid uiautomator hierarchy file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052849/unexpected-error-while-parsing-input-invalid-uiautomator-hierarchy-file)